OpenConnect answers with 404, updating config workaround
0
This started a few weeks ago. Every time when I try to login on VPN OpenConnect (version 9.12-1build5 on Kubuntu 24.04) with username and password. When I click enter and expect to be taken to the 2pass auth page it will fail with "Unexpected 404 result from server":

I go into the syslog when doing it and it outputs just one single line:
024-10-04T08:17:19.667533+02:00 iluvatar4 kded5[3835]: QFormLayout::takeAt: Invalid index 0

Then I go into VPN configuration and alter the path, press Apply, revert the change, press Apply again and voilà I can log in without hassle.
Has anyone seen anything similar; is there a workaround?

Updated the wrong information. It was 24.04; I don't know why I thought it was otherwise.
